# Correlation of two 1d point processes with non-uniform unconditional distribution

Tags: correlation, cross-correlation, point-process

I want to measure the correlation between two 1D point processes $x$ and $y$. Ordinarily I could use the bivariate K-function

$K(t) = \frac{T}{n_xn_y} \sum_{i=1}^{n_x} \sum_{j=1}^{n_y} w(x_i,y_j) I[d(x_i,y_j)<t]$

where $n_x$ is the number of observations in $x$ and $n_y$ is the number of observations in $y$. Deviation from $K(t)=t$ is an indication of correlation between the two point processes.

However, my analysis is complicated by the fact that the unconditional distributions of the point processes are non-uniform. They each have a characteristic distribution of intervals between observations, which could be different for $x$ and $y$.

To make things more complicated, the intensities vary over the time period (for example, the intensity might be low around midnight and higher during daylight hours).

Assuming I have enough data to get good estimates of the unconditional distributions of $x$ and $y$, and of the way that intensities vary across time, is there a way to take this into account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  The key is that how you *measure* correlation does not change, but the expected value does depend on the hypothesized underlying process.

$K$ (and cross-$K$, which is what you are looking at) is defined generally for inhomogeneous point processes.  For a good discussion with examples see [Philip Dixon's analysis](http://www.stat.iastate.edu/preprint/articles/2001-18.pdf).  Because all his examples are 2D, the specific formulas for expectations do not apply directly to your 1D data, but all the general ideas do apply.  Note that with non-uniform distributions the definition (and computation) of $K$ do not change, but the expectation does change.  With non-stationary distributions you also have to take care to distinguish the two forms of cross-K between your two series of data.

Comment: Thanks. So let's say that the $K$ functions for processes $x$ and $y$ are given by $K_x(t)$ and $K_y(t)$. How do I test the hypothesis that $x$ is independent of $y$? Under the assumption of stationarity I can simply look at $L_{xy}(t) = \sqrt{K_{xy}(t)/\pi}$ and look for departures from $L_{xy}(t)-t=0$. For non-stationary distributions I see that $K_{xy}(t)$ will in general be different from $K_{yx}(t)$, but I don't see what the impact of this on my hypothesis testing should be.

Comment: You have to redo the calculations for 1D and your particular assumptions, Chris: the formulas you quote are for 2D and a homogeneous process.  Dixon's references provide the theory.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little weird to answer my own question, but...

To address the non-stationarity issue, it seems as though it's not particularly tricky to compute the expected $K$-function under the hypothesis of independent event times. In particular, let's say that we're looking at point processes on the interval $I=[0,T]$, and our processes $X$ and $Y$ have unconditional distributions $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$. We'll also denote the unit ball in one dimension by $B(x,t) = \{y\in I:d(x,y)<t\}$. Then

$K_{XY}(t) = \mathbb{E}[\textrm{number of Y points in a neighbourhood t of a randomly chosen X point}]$

$K_{XY}(t) = \mathbb{E}_X[\mathbb{E}_Y[\textrm{number of Y points within t of x}]]$

$K_{XY}(t) = \int_I dx \int_{B(x,t)} dy \, f_X(x) f_Y(y)$

So deviations from this function in the estimated $\hat{K}_{XY}(t)$ will be an indicator of correlation between the point processes.

Does this sound reasonable?

---

Edit: In fact, I think this all holds if you take $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and interpret $x$, $y$ as vectors.

Comment: This is the point of departure in Dixon's survey I referenced.

Comment: Yes, I think I understand now. I didn't grasp the full range of your answer when I read it the first time!